# How to add mocks to local build?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular to create library project to create web-components. So my project in /projects folder; /src is used for local page to check library.

My mocks are added into /src module - so when loading library as Angular module, they works.

But how to add them into main.js bundle? Like, if this is prod build - don't include mocks; if this local build - include mocks.

How to choose what service will be loaded to module at build time? Or how can I create build sequence for production-like bundle but with mocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to choose what service will be loaded to module at build time?

You can conditionally import Module (and thus services in this module) based e.g. on `environment.production` flag.

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ...,
        environment.production ? [] : MockModule   // THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
    ],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In the example above you import your `MockModule` to the app only for production build, otherwise you import empty array.

`Angular.json` file has `fileReplacements` section, where you can specify different files for different build configuration (dev, prod, etc.).

`environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` should be available out of the box if you generated project via `ng` cli, but you can also update `fileReplacements` section (of your desired build configuration, e.g. production) with your own configuration and use other files, if you it suites you better.

```js
// angular.json
"fileReplacements": [
    {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
],
```

Comment: But isn't it bad to import anything outside library to library? Like, src/environments is not part of library in projects/library folder

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your project set-up.  Maybe if you can update question with example structure that would help.

Comment: What I thought you are asking is, how to conditionally import services/modules based on the build type prod/dev. When building the library, you don't have to use files outside the library folder. You can put `environment.ts` file inside library's `src` folder and then reference this file in your build configuration of a library project portion of your angular.json. So I think the answer will still solve your problem, just place `environment.ts` inside the library folder, where you want to have it.